# Building a d3.js widget in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, d3.js, dom, dart

I'm getting started with flutter and trying build a Stateful Widget, which when called would display a d3.js chart.  My thinking is to build a chart into a stateful widget and use the changenotifier provider to update the chart data, and d3.js has beautiful plots.

I've found a couple of other references of other people doing similar things...

[Dart js interop with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533207/dart-js-interop-with-d3)

[How to embed a D3 chart in a Polymer.dart element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487606/how-to-embed-a-d3-chart-in-a-polymer-dart-element).

It seems to make sense that if I already had an element in my html code that I could reference from my dart code I could attach to that, and create my plot - as in the latter reference...

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
js.context['d3'].callMethod('select', [shadowRoot.querySelector('.chart')]);
```

What I don't understand, is how I would be able to create that .chart element in the DOM within my stateful widget itself so that from the perspective of my dart code, it sees it as just a dart widget.

Put another way, what is it than I can select that is local to the widget itself so that I can nest the resulting widget in other widgets?

Is wanting to wrap the d3.js in a stateful widget in dart something that could be accomplished in a relatively encapsulated way?  And is trying to create the html within the widget itself a good approach?

Comment: Hey Flaminator, could you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no I didn't.  I ended up using vue.js instead of flutter for the project as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best you could do is to use [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and run javascript code (for example, draw d3.js chart) inside this webview.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/plotly_js was web compatible only when posting. An actual port would be nice.